# WordPress theme blog not displaying well in FireFox-how to fix?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have recently made a new WordPress theme (named {cssgroundup}) which I am using on my blog at [www.richard-dickinson.com](http://www.richard-dickinson.com)

It is only a basic WP theme for my personal use as I am quite new to the WordPress platform (?). It is a work in progress (as is the blog content!) however it displays alright in IE browser but not so well in FireFox.

Can someone help me edit it so it displays properly in most browsers or advise me how I can fix this please? I have asked for help at wordpress.org forums but haven't yet had any help!
I can post stylesheet code & theme.php code here if required.

I look forward to helpful replies, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to do is fix your code errors: [Markup Validation of  richard-dickinson.com  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//richard-dickinson.com/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Fix the bad code on line 628, and then revaldiate and see what else is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your reply songdogtech. I validated the layout html with W3C validator before creating the theme but I will try revalidation & try fixing whatever the problem is.

I really need more help with stylesheet and layout and WordPress theme tags and coding and getting this to run properly in all browsers. I am grateful for help and advice on those issues, thanks

Answer (score 0):

rpd, it would be useful for those of us who want to help you if you spelled out specific problems that you are trying to find answers to. An example might look like "In IE my top level navigation is working the way I want. In Firefox, the *sitemap* link is on the next line. How do I fix this?"

There are a lot of cool, generous people here who are happy to share their knowledge with you, but very few people have time to just sit down and review your site from top to bottom.

Comment: Hi Clay
Thanks for your reply and help. I will try to be more specific!
I have been rediting my theme and redid the css layout and it validated so hopefully that issue is done! My 2 issues now are that 1.I appear to have lost my logo div! (with background image)
2.In IE the crumpled paper content div background displays all the way across the content div but it only displays partly across the div in Firefox.

I will continue to try editing this myself but I am grateful for help and advice to sort these 2 issues. Thanks

Comment: UPDATE:
I seem to have solved the missing logo div issue
but I still need to sort the content div issue (it displays in IE but not in Firefox)

Comment: Further Update:
I did not manage to fix the content div display and decided to work on this in slow time on my Xampp local host webserver and meanwhile I have a new theme live on my website which I am developing.

So onward with WordPress themes and development...